# Vector Usage in MPI(C++)

Tags: c++, vector, parallel-processing, mpi

I am new to MPI programming,stiil learning , i was successful till  creating the Derived data-types by defining the structures . Now i want to include Vector in my structure and want to send the data across the Process. for ex:

```
struct Structure{

//Constructor 
Structure(): X(nodes),mass(nodes),ac(nodes) {

//code to calculate the mass and accelerations
}
//Destructor
Structure() {}

//Variables
double radius;
double volume;
vector<double> mass;
vector<double> area;

//and some other variables

//Methods to calculate some physical properties
```

Now using MPI i want to sent the data in the structure across the processes. Is it possible for me to create the MPI_type_struct vectors included and send the data?

I tried reading through forums, but i am not able to get the clear picture from the responses given there. Hope i would be able to get a clear idea or approach to send the data

PS: i can send the data individually , but its an overhead of sending the data using may MPI_Send/Recieve if we consider the domain very large(say 10000*10000)

Answer (score 14):

Defining structures in MPI is a pain. I think an easier approach would be to use the fact that STL vectors are guaranteed to have contiguously allocated memory. That is, you can treat them like C arrays by getting a pointer to the first element.

```
std::vector<float> data;
// ... add elements to your vector ...
MPI_Send(&data.front(), data.size(), MPI_FLOAT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response , the problem here i want to send the whole structure at one time instead of sending single variable of vectorand other data-types thereby reducing the communication overhead between the processes...and i have 10 vectors to be sent across for communication ....hence it leading to slow computation time and there by decreasing the efficiency

Comment: @lsk1985, OK I'm not experienced enough with MPI to be of much help then. Sorry. I would just be careful to avoid sending pointers between processes (instead of the data they point to).

Comment: If you have an array of pointers, create an MPI_Type_hindexed, which is a row of blocks, with displacement expressed in bytes. It only takes a little address arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

I describe my solution to a similar problem here:

[Message Passing Arbitrary Object Graphs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345615/message-passing-arbitrary-object-graphs/2380252#2380252)

Remember that you can create custom MPI datatypes from prevoiusly defined custom MPI datatypes. For instance, you can define a Struct that describes the layout and content of a single instance of Structure, then a Vector from these Struct datatypes for the entire vector of objects. Heck, if you have several such vectors, you can create a third layer of abstraction, creating a HIndexed datatype from Vectors of Structs, and then send them all with a single message.

In the post I linked above you will find links to the descriptions of the various custom MPI datatypes, that should help you decide on the proper approach.

Comment: Thanks for the link and your idea how to approach the problem

Answer (score 0):

I do stuff like you're doing, and I know my processor architecture is homogenous. I avoid lots of byte-swapping and lots of MPI packing and unpacking by using [Boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html).

Sending:

```
  ostringstream oss;
  {
    binary_oarchive oa(oss);
    oa << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(myStruct);
  }

  MPI::COMM_WORLD.Send(oss.str().c_str(),
                       oss.str().size(),
                       MPI::Datatype(MPI_BYTE),
                       MpiLibWrapper::DEST_PROC_RANK,
                       MpiLibWrapper::MY_STRUCT_TAG);
```

Receiving:

```
    vector<char> incomingBuffer(MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);

    MPI::COMM_WORLD.Recv(&incomingBuffer[0], incomingBuffer.size(),
                         MPI::Datatype(MPI_BYTE),
                         MpiLibWrapper::SRC_PROC_RANK,
                         MpiLibWrapper::MY_STRUCT_TAG,
                         msgStatus);
    if (MpiLibWrapper::ErrorOccurred(msgStatus.Get_error(),
                                     info.logging)) {
      break;
    }
    incomingBuffer.resize(msgStatus.Get_count(MPI::Datatype(MPI_BYTE)));

    if (incomingBuffer.size() > 0) {
      // Shockingly, this does not result in a memory allocation.
      istringstream iss(string(&incomingBuffer[0], incomingBuffer.size()));

      binary_iarchive ia(iss);

      ia >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(myStruct);
    }
```

Comment: I have no idea on Boost Serialization, may be i need to spend some time understanding it and see if it solves the problem i have.Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Sending C/C++ struct as a stream of data works only when you are guaranteed that the data layout on all participating machines is exactly the same. In general, this will not work. Plus, there are people who'd argue that sending a structure packed as an MPI derived data type is +1 for clarity of the code, and to  show the intent.

Answer (score -2):

I'm certainly not an MPI data structure expert, but I don't think that this can be done.  The reason is that basically you have a structure with pointers to the data to be sent. All of the MPI datatype functions assume that the data you want to send is in a contiguous area of memory. If the vectors are of a fixed maximum size, and you could do

```
double radius;
double volume;
int mass_size;
int area_size;
double mass[MASS_MAXLEN];
double area[AREA_MAXLEN];
```

and then send only the elements that are filled in.

Alternatively, you could pack the data yourself into one array prior to the send and send the array.  You would have to do some profiling to see if this was faster than doing separate sends.

Comment: yes, i need to try and see if sending individual vectors works out simpler , Thanks for the Suggestion

Comment: "All of the MPI datatype functions assume that the data you want to send is in a contiguous area of memory." -- while this is true, you can define custom MPI datatypes that represent an arbitrary memory layout (see my answer). So, you can define a datatype from your pointers, then send a message as a single instance of this datatype, thus achieving the required result.