# MPI BCast (broadcast) of a std::vector of structs

Tags: c++, vector, mpi, openmpi

I've got a question regarding passing of a std::vector of structs via MPI.

First off, details.  I'm using  OpenMPI 1.4.3  (MPI-2 compliant)  with gcc.
Note that I can't use boost MPI or OOMPI -- I'm bound to using this version.

I've got a struct to aggregate some data:

```
  struct Delta {
    Delta() : dX(0.0), dY(0.0), dZ(0.0) {};
    Delta(double dx, double dy, double dz) :
      dX(dx), dY(dy), dZ(dz) {};
    Delta(const Delta& rhs) :
      dX(rhs.dX), dY(rhs.dY), dZ(rhs.dZ) {};

    double dX;
    double dY;
    double dZ;
  };

  typedef std::vector<Delta> DeltaLine;
```

and I have a DeltaLine that I'd like to broadcast, via MPI, to all the nodes.

Can I do the following safely and portably?
This works for me in my test case.  I just want to make sure it's legal and kosher across different platforms and according to the C++ and MPI standards.

Thanks!
Madeleine.

```
  //Create an MPI struct for the Delta class
  const int    nItems=3;
  int          blocklengths[nItems] = {1, 1, 1};
  MPI_Datatype types[nItems] = {MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_DOUBLE};
  MPI_Datatype MPI_DeltaType;
  MPI_Aint     offsets[nItems];

  offsets[0] = offsetof(Delta, dX);
  offsets[1] = offsetof(Delta, dY);
  offsets[2] = offsetof(Delta, dZ);

  MPI_Type_create_struct(nItems, blocklengths, offsets, types, &MPI_DeltaType);
  MPI_Type_commit(&MPI_DeltaType);

  //This is the vector to be filled, and its size
  DeltaLine deltaLine;
  unsigned deltaLineSize;

  //If this is the master proc, get the DeltaLine and its size
  if(amMaster()) {
    deltaLine = getMasterDeltaLine();
    deltaLineSize = deltaLine.size();
  }

  //Send out the correct size
  MPI_Bcast(&deltaLineSize, 1, MPI_UNSIGNED, COMM_PROC, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  //Size the delta line vector, and broadcast its contents
  deltaLine.reserve(deltaLineSize);
  MPI_Bcast(&deltaLine.front(), deltaLineSize, MPI_DeltaType, COMM_PROC, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  //Free up the type
  MPI_Type_free(&MPI_DeltaType);
```

Comment: Just for completeness sake: In order to avoid with padding issues mentioned by Hristo, and the size vs capacity issue I mentioned, on could also follow an approach that represents the data as a flat, 1-dimensional array (plain double* or contained in a std::valarray, e.g.) of 3*N size and transmit a "stride" (= 3) along with the number N of tuples in a first BCast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++ standard guarantees that the elements of `std::vector` are stored contiguously in memory and that `std::vector::reserve()` (re-)allocates memory if necessary at the time of call, therefore your solution is perfectly valid from memory management point of view. Though, as Solkar noted, `std::vector::reserve()` only reserves memory space but the vector object is not aware that there is data being directly written in that memory and therefore keeps the previous element count (zero for freshly created vectors). This can be fixed by calling `std::vector::resize()` before the second broadcast operation.

One comment though that applies to all cases when constructed MPI datatypes are used to send arrays - you should take care of possible padding between the consecutive array elements. In other words, it is possible for the following to hold because of possible padding at the end of the `struct`:

```
(char*)&deltaLine[1] - (char*)&deltaLine[0] != mpi_extentof(MPI_DeltaType)
```

where `mpi_extentof` is the extent of the MPI datatype as returned by `MPI_Type_get_extent()`. Because MPI uses the extent to determine where each array element starts, it is advisable to explicitly set it for any structure type that is used to send more than one element. With MPI-1 this is typically done by adding one special structure element of the `MPI_UB` pseudotype, but in modern MPI code (or in MPI-2 in general) one should use `MPI_Type_create_resized` for that purpose:

```
//Create an MPI struct for the Delta class
const int    nItems=3;
int          blocklengths[nItems] = {1, 1, 1};
MPI_Datatype types[nItems] = {MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_DOUBLE};
MPI_Datatype MPI_DeltaType_proto, MPI_DeltaType;
MPI_Aint     offsets[nItems];

offsets[0] = offsetof(Delta, dX);
offsets[1] = offsetof(Delta, dY);
offsets[2] = offsetof(Delta, dZ);

MPI_Type_create_struct(nItems, blocklengths, offsets, types, &MPI_DeltaType_proto);

// Resize the type so that its length matches the actual structure length

// Get the constructed type lower bound and extent
MPI_Aint lb, extent;
MPI_Type_get_extent(MPI_DeltaType_proto, &lb, &extent);

// Get the actual distance between to vector elements
// (this might not be the best way to do it - if so, substitute a better one)
extent = (char*)&deltaLine[1] - (char*)&deltaLine[0];

// Create a resized type whose extent matches the actual distance
MPI_Type_create_resized(MPI_DeltaType_proto, lb, extent, &MPI_DeltaType);
MPI_Type_commit(&MPI_DeltaType);
```

In your case there are only `double` elements in the structure and no padding is expected, therefore doing this all is not necessary. But keep it in mind for your future work with MPI.

Comment: "The C++ standard guarantees that the elements of std::vector are stored contiguously in memory and that std::vector::reserve() (re-)allocates memory if necessary at the time of call, therefore your solution is perfectly valid." As I already mentioned: reserve(N) and subsequent writing directly to the float* pointed to by &front() does not affect size() of the vector, so that fills the vector with data that is not accessible using the standard vector interface.

Comment: So one should use `resize()` instead?

Comment: Yes, and that takes us also to questions of efficiency (likely not in this case, but imagine a sample with more frequent resizing needs). I've read that you work a lot with hpc - do you have any hard figures about optimized valarray implementations available?

Comment: Actually no. Most codes that I work with are written in Fortran and they operate with simple arrays - no fancy C++ abstractions there.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector::reserve(N)` does not affect `size` but (if at all) `capacity` (and maybe location), so for the receiving containers `deltaLine` will still be a zero size vector, regardless of its `capacity` equaling `deltaLineSize`.

That's not yet a problem in the code as-is, but I assume you intend to do some processing using the received data.

I would also check the return value of (at least) the first `MPI_BCast`, because if that, for whatever reason fails on one process, the vector's size there would be 0, and if it responds to the second broadcast bounds will be violated.

Comment: The default error handler in MPI is `MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL` and you either get `MPI_SUCCESS` from all MPI calls or your program terminates abnormally if there is an error.

Comment: Relying on hard aborts to avoid abort by access violation is like exorcising the Devil with Beelzebub.